# How can we see text under a scrollbar in the Stack Overflow code section?

Tags: support, design

How we can see text under a scrollbar in the Stack Overflow code section?

Please see the following screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Turn off the silly "auto-hide scrollbars" preference in your operating system.